# how can get an alert on “aged files” in Azure Storage Account Containers?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have Azure Storage Account which contains files in Blob Container. I want to send alert, if a file is sitting in one of the sub folders in a container for more than a day.

So, can anyone suggest me how we can get an alert on “aged files” in Azure Storage Account Containers.

Comment: Maybe you can use `Recurrence` trigger in `azure logic app` to run the workflow once a day. You can get blob's metadata such as `LastModified` to compare with the current time. If the time difference is more than 24 hours, you can send an e-mail to remind yourself. My only concern is that if it runs once a day, there may be blobs that exist for nearly two days before being discovered, so I want to ask if you have any requirements for timeliness.

Comment: Yes Frank Gong, I have the requirements for the timeliness. If possible please share code to get blob's `LastModified` time to compare with the `CurrentTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I designed a workflow in `azure logic app`. You can use `Azure Storage Blob` connecter to list blobs in your container, then you can use `for each` to traverse your blobs:

[image]

[image]

Within the `for each` action, you need to use `condition` action to compare its time. Here, I use the current time minus 24 hours to compare with the last modified time of the blob.

[image]

**addHours expression**

```
addHours(utcNow('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'),-24,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

=================update========================

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I want to get aged files from multiple folders inside the Azure Storage Account, is Logic app designer right solutions or not? For this problem, I can add parallel action but I have so many folders.

Comment: I think logic app can handle your problem, but `List blobs` action can only specify one container at a time. If you want to process blobs in multiple containers at the same time, perhaps you can create multiple logic apps.

Comment: I have single container with multiple folders and eachsubfolder having one common sub folder. For example: `Container Name> Folder Name> Common Sub Folder Name`

Comment: If your directory hierarchy has only two levels, then logic apps can handle it, but it’s a little troublesome to do so. Because `List blobs` can only retrieve the next hierarchy(blob or directory), you need to use `List blobs` action again within `for each` action . You need to use `List blobs (path metadata from List blobs)` three times in total.

Comment: Hi, @Pradeep. Sorry for not replying to your follow-up question in time, I saw that you deleted your comment today, I don’t know if you have solved your problem, I have updated the new solution in my answer. Hope to give you some inspiration.

Comment: Is there any way to capture exception details in case of any action failed in the logic app

Comment: Frank Gong, is there any way to identify whether the root folder contains sub folders or files?

Comment: @Pradeep. Whether the problem is solved, I was on vacation some time ago, if it has not been solved, you can post a new post and I can help you solve it.

Comment: Frank Gond, If possible please update your answer.